# How to show $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits, inner-products

Let $f(x) = \langle Ax,x\rangle + 2\langle x,b\rangle +c$ where $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}, b \in \mathbb R^n, c \in \mathbb R$, $A$ is positive definite.

I want to show that $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$

I know $\langle Ax,x\rangle$ is positive, but maybe $\langle x,b \rangle$ is negative so it evens out. It feels like there's some identity with inner products or formula that I'm missing, possible some trick with Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: You can even complete the square in higher dimensions, expand $\langle A(x+y),x+y\rangle$ and choose $y$ to match up the linear term with $\langle x,b\rangle$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $\vec x=\vec u t$ with $t\to \infty$ then

$$f(x) = t^2\langle Au,u\rangle + 2t\langle u,b\rangle +c$$

Comment: ...God damn it.